# Why input type=file not working with $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, struts2

I have a `<s:file>` tag inside the form which generates a HTML `<input type="file">`. When I submit the form via form submission (e.g. submit button, etc.) everything works fine in the action method. However, when I change my code to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "actionClass!actionMethodA.action",
    type: "POST",
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error ' + textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            },
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
                ...
            }
});
```

In the backend, the `file` field is always `null`.

The file field is defined in  the action class as follow (with setter and getter):

```
private File impFileUrl;
```

Is it because now the form is serialized so that the file field can no longer be set properly in the backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because [jQuery.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) serializes only input elements, not the data in them.

> Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit
>   button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a
>   button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized
>   string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes
>   and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included
>   only if they are checked. **Data from file select elements is not
>   serialized.**

But it doesn't mean that you can't upload files with ajax. Additional features or plugins might be used to send [`FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

> You can also use `FormData` with jQuery if you set the right options:
>
> ```
> var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
> fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
> $.ajax({
>   url: "actionClass!actionMethodA.action",
>   type: "POST",
>   data: fd,
>   processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
>   contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
> });
> ```